# Change the EXPLORER title to workspace name

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the word `EXPLORER` in the sidebar to the name of the workspace folder?
And maybe to increase the font size a little bit?

If not, is this reachable by an extension?

#### edit after the first comment

[image]

Yes, the workspacefolder name is the root folder in the treeview.
But for me it would be faster and easier to recognize if not the string `EXPLORER` stays on top, instead `SK-AUTH-PRISMA`.
Maybe in a little increased fontsize.

Comment: the name of the workspace folder is part of the Title of the View with the files.

Comment: @rioV8 I edited my question to make my issue more clear

Comment: why would you want that? It already says the name of the workspace right under that in all caps. On top of that, that's not what UI section is for. It's to say what side panel you've currently selected (Search, Source Control, Run and Debug, etc.)